# Showing 0 covariance for special form of AR(1) time series

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance, autoregressive

This is an exercise I have been trying to solve but have not made much progress.

Suppose $\{Z_t\}$ is an AR(1) process with $\rho_1 = \phi$. Define the sequence $\{b_t\}$ as $b_t = Z_t - \phi Z_{t+1}$.

Show that $Cov(b_t, b_{t-k}) = 0$ for all $t$ and $k$.

Show that $Cov(b_t,b_{t+k}) = 0$ for all $t$ and $k > 0$.

I've tried rearranging the terms, for instance writing $b_t = (1-\phi^2)Z_t - W_{t+1}$ (where $W_t$ is white noise from the AR(1)). I then wrote this in linear form:

$$(1-\phi^2)(\phi^tZ_0 + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{t-1}\phi^iW_{t-i}) - W_{t+1}$$

And then calculating covariance the usual way, $E(b_tb_{t-k}) - E(b_t)E(b_{t-k})$ but it did not result in the expected solution; in fact I could not reduce it to simple terms. Is there some property or rearrangement I can use to solve this?

Comment: You missed a $\phi$ coefficient before $W_{t+1}$ in the formula for $b_t$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you have a missing $\phi$ before $W_{t+1}$. But, you don't need to go that way either. Let $\operatorname{cov}(Z_t,Z_t)=\gamma_0$, and an AR(1) process have $\rho_k=\phi^{|k|}$:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(b_t,b_{t-k})&=\operatorname{cov}(Z_t-\phi Z_{t+1},Z_{t-k}-\phi Z_{t-k+1})\\&=\gamma_0(\rho_k-\phi\rho_{k-1}-\phi \rho_{k+1}+\phi^2\rho_k)\\&=\gamma_0(\phi^{|k|}-\phi^{1+|k-1|}-\phi^{|k+1|+1}+\phi^{2+|k|})\end{align}$$

This is $0$ when $k\geq 1$ or $k\leq -1$, which satisfies both of the cases, i.e. $\operatorname{cov}(b_t,b_{t\pm k})$. This cannot be $0$ for $k=0$ because it is the same RV.